# What is the difference between Power control and Power allocation?

Tags: wireless, ad-hoc-wireless

In the context of wireless communication (specifically device-to-device communication) what is the difference between Power control and Power allocation. I guess the latter is a form of resource allocation however, it seems some researchers (or authors) use them interchangeably. Could anyone clarify this?

An example of such is this [Page 10, bottom left](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6161.pdf)

> One interesting point is that the
>   performance degradation of the cellular user is not significant
>   as the number of D2D links increases when the centralized
>   power allocation method is applied because the proposed admission control ensures that the uplink user is protected. This
>   implies that the centralized power control method is able to
>   support reliable uplink performance regardless of the density
>   of D2D links.

Another is this [Page 1, right column, second paragraph](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07041.pdf)

> Apart from resource allocation, power control is also a key
>   technique to achieve high performance [5]–[9]. The authors in
>   [5] applied a simple power control method to D2D communications, which constrains the signal to interference-plus-noise
>   ratio (SINR) degradation of the cellular link to a certain level.
>   In [6], the optimum power allocation for different resource
>   sharing modes was derived.

Comment: Can you provide some links or quotes?  It’s helpful to see the terms in context.

Comment: Thanks, Ron, I have added more details.